# MySQLIi is not accepting my database login details

Tags: php, mysqli

Below is my code that I am using. I know that the details are correct as they are identical to another page that connects to the database fine. However with this code I get the error: 
`Access denied for user 'un'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. Can anyone tell me what it is i'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'un';
$password = 'pw';
$dbname = 'db';

$user = 'admin_uk';
$password = 'r04ryuk';

if($connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname)){
    echo 'slup';
}else{
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: you've got two sets of usernames and passwords there. you might be getting them mixed up.

Comment: nicely spotted! it was all a test! seriously though thanks, this has been driving me nuts for ages!

Answer (score 0):

What's different between this snippet and the one that works fine? Are they both run locally? Same user? Same password? Same database?

I'm guessing you're having a problem with permissions. Maybe the 'un' user doesn't have access to the 'db' database?

Answer (score 0):

You should check to make sure that the 'un' user is actually setup to connect to 'localhost'.  I've had a couple problems where I had to tweak those.

After that, make sure to FLUSH PRIVILEGES after any changes.